# Customizing date picker dialog android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to change the background,text color and the typeface of datepicker dialog along with it i want to change customize the positive and negative buttons on it as well.. How is it possible ?

Comment: have you found this link  https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider

Comment: See..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112534/using-datepicker-on-custom-dialog, http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/browse_thread/thread/0843d3b0cd7aedb9, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select date from dialog and display it in TextView.

```
public class DatePickerDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // capture our View elements
    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date (this method is below)
    updateDisplay();
}

// updates the date in the TextView
private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.strSelectedDate,
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" ")));
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If none of the prebuilt widgets or layouts meets your needs, you can create your own View subclass. If you only need to make small adjustments to an existing widget or layout, you can simply subclass the widget or layout and override its methods.
>
> Creating your own View subclasses gives you precise control over the
>   appearance and function of a screen element.

Source : [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

However, you can easily [extend the existing one and create your own](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying).

Also, if you are just willing to pimp your UI, you could have a look at the [DateSlider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/).

Answer (score 1):

if you want spinner type date picker then [this](https://github.com/SingleCycleKing/CustomTimePicker) one is good. you can customize everthing