# Making Custom date picker in android?

Tags: android, monthcalendar, datapicker, custom-datetimepicker

I am sure,I think my question is something different in android.I goggled 100s of sites i saw the date picker in android, all are same type, no one give the different date picker.

My Task is to design custom date picker. Please find this below screen shot.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obZzVreHpmdnZBYzg/edit?usp=sharing

For that I goggled, I didn't find any solution. I think, For android solutions this is the best site.

coming to my date picker it is totally dialog box. In that red symbol,name,close mark,submit i can do it. But i want that sun,man,tue,web In red color and on the top month and year. In below dates with green color picker. so Please tell me how can I do that task.

All advices are accepted.

Thanks&Regards

Shankar
Clite

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292279/customizing-date-picker-dialog-android

Comment: try this link it may help you http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest how I would have gone for such a calendar. By the UI it is clear that it has to come as a pop-up or to better say a `dialog`. Now you have to google the opensource calendars if any or just using the `calendar API` provided by java you can get the calendar for a month year etc. and move it across previous month by normal java function calls.

Now that you have got the data to populate in your calendar. You have to design a custom layout `xml` create **~30-40** boxes or a grid with dynamic `textviews` or a **webview** with `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` the choice is completely yours.

AFAIK

If you can't find anything opensource then I would suggest you should do these things by the suggested approach.